# Outputting html for liberator's handle-unauthorized

Tags: clojure, compojure, liberator

I am using liberator with ring/compojure and would like to handle authorization using the liberator `defresource` macros.  I can easily get `handle-ok` to output html that is recognized by the browser, but `handle-unauthorized` will have the html output in `pre` tags.

I'm suspecting that my not being able to find out how to do this means that there is a good reason not to do it this way.  All the examples I see online show `handle-unauthorized` returning text, but I was hoping to display a custom page.

Here is (one version of) the code I was using.  I am using Hiccup:

```
(defresource deny-all
  :authorized? (fn [_] false)
  :available-media-types ["text/html"]
  :handle-ok (fn [ctx] (html5 [:body [:h1 "Yes!"]])))
  :handle-unauthorized (fn [ctx] (html5 [:body [:h1 "Noooo!"]])))
```

What I get back from the browser is a literal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><h1>Noooo!</h1></body></html>
</pre>
```

If I change `authorized?` to return true, then it outputs the html correctly.

I've tried returning ring-style responses, but those raise errors too.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In REST talk, html is one of many possible representations of a resource. Since the resource is unauthorized, no representation should be returned, html or otherwise. Instead, the client, instructed by the 401 status error, should take a different course of action, such as requesting a login page.

Most apps written in web frameworks will not return a 401, but instead redirect to the authorization page. This is possible in Liberator too, because nothing stops you from handling the authorization in the resource itself (handle-ok with logic).

This might be a breach of practice. I posted an [issue](https://github.com/clojure-liberator/liberator/issues/69) on Liberator's github to ask for the opinion of people more knowledgeable in the recipes of RESTful cooking.

At any rate, the reason you see your html wrapped in a pre tag is the result of the following factors:

1. Content negotiation is not available for unauthorized resources in Liberator. The 401's body is always of type text/plain.
2. When you specify a html string as the response, it will render as is.
3. When using Chrome development tools, upon inspecting the source, you will see the html string wrapped in a `pre` tag.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it does.  I see also from the link you posted that, were I to insist on sending html, then I could do it via `:handle-unauthorized (fn [_] (liberator.representation/ring-response {:body "go away" :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}})))`